# Extreme lag when opening menus, folders, programs, just about anything that has to load new graphics

Tags: windows, windows-10, lag

This is an intermittent issue.  I've gone months without it present at all, and months with it present.

The lag affects everything except audio.  Input and all visuals are frozen for the duration of the lag/stutter, including games, video, etc.  It is very difficult to move the mouse around accurately during, because it doesn't catch up to expected location, it actually stops receiving input.
[image: ultra lag example]
*CPU mislabeled! i have an R9 3950x with SMT disabled. Most cpu usage is task manager and ShareX (recording gif 24fps); openshell is not at fault either, just demonstrating menus with it.*
Honestly it feels worse than it looks, 24fps gif makes it look less bad.

Restarting pc solves it temporarily when it rears it's ugly face, but only temporarily.  I've been trying to pin down the cause of this for years, searching every corner of the internet for solutions, but nothing seems to definitively exterminate the problem.  It has persisted through total hardware replacements over the years.  I have also run into this in previous windows installs (various versions), and multiple different driver versions (AMD).  The issue appears and disappears independently of driver or other installations.

** edit: for added contextual example, when the lag is present, even dragging chrome tabs between windows becomes stuttery, as well as file or image drag&drop, and even the file/edit etc menus in gimp.

It seems to happen after something crashes, perhaps graphics related, which lead me to think maybe it's video memory issues?  Ctrl+Shift+Win+B has no effect, manually disabling and reenabling the GPU driver device has no effect.  Restarting DWM has no effect.  There is no detected DPC Latency.  No discernible programs are affecting it.  I have most non-essentials in windows disabled: no cortana, no telemetry, no updates, no unwanted indexing.

Speaking of windows updates; this doesn't come from updates, because my pc never updates unless i tell it to, i'm very scorched earth with update policy.  The issue has come and gone without any changes to OS.

All of that said, what could possibly be the issue?  I've run out of troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Windows 10 is old enough that 32-bit context extension Apps were common and need to be updated to the 64-bit counterpart.  Nirsoft ShellView may hep you with this. Also, Adobe and Office should all be 64-bit